# How to combine two strings (date & time) into a new date in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, date

I am trying to combine two date strings into a format that will allow for a new single date. The first string is a .long style format string. The second string is just a time string. The values look like this:

```
let date = "March 24, 2017"
let time = "7:00 AM"
```

I Need to combine these strings to form a new date that works as iOS swift date. I have tried various DateFormatters and merging the strings together but the combination of .Long for date and .short for time does not seem to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let date = "March 24, 2017"
let time = "7:00 AM"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mm a"
let string = date + " at " + time                       // "March 24, 2017 at 7:00 AM"
let finalDate = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
print(finalDate?.description(with: .current) ?? "")  // "Friday, March 24, 2017 at 7:00:00 AM Brasilia Standard Time"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick turn around, I was missing the "at" part. Regards.

Comment: There's no need to put the `" at "` between the two strings and in the formatter. Just use a space.

Comment: @LeoDabus But there's nothing to read. The goal is to create a `Date`, not a `String`. You certainly don't need a more readable string to parse it into a `Date`.

Comment: @rmaddy well looking at it this way not even a space is needed

Comment: @LeoDabus Probably not.